# How to provide access to main activity/context to other classes that need it?

Tags: java, android

This is how I'm providing access to my main activity to all classes that require a context and/or need to call methods within my main activity class:

```
public interface InterfaceMainActiv {
    ActMain getMainActiv();
}
```

I know this is super bad form, but is it ok to just hand out access to your main activity where required? Will do so break anything? @OutOfBounds 94 Specifically I'm worried about this warning:
[image]

Comment: Could you specify what kind of classes you wish to give access to context, is it like a RecyclerView adapter?

Comment: I basically am using the context in many different classes so they can get handles on layouts via `findViewById(R.id.view_name)`. Also I'm passing reference to main activity so I can call it's methods from these other classes. I know I should probably detail each of these methods in the interface that than just handing out the entire main activity right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interfaces!

1. Create an interface with methods that you want to call and they require context. Lets say you have `interface Demo` which has the method `doSomething(Param a);`
2. Implement that interface in the activity that will be active ATM when you would call this method. So basically you will have `MyActivity implements Demo` and that activity has `doSomething(Param a)` method with context available.
3. Make the constructor of the class from which you want to call the method take the Demo interface as the parameter. So for ex. `public MyAdapter(Demo demo)`. And then when constructing the object, pass the activity implementing that interface - `new MyAdapter(myActivity)`
4. Call interface method inside your class (`demo.doSomething(data)`), it will be executed inside the activity. Pass all the data that you need to work on through the params of the interface method.
5. Profit???

This comes down to the basic principles of OOP.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but why should I [use inferfaces (implements) rather than inheritence (extends)](http://www.cs.pomona.edu/~kim/CSC051F13/Lectures/Lecture28/Lecture28_7.html) in this case? Basically I just want to call (reuse) the parent activity's methods.

Comment: Extending the activity extends also the context onto your object which may live longer than its parent activity which would end up as a leak again because your object would be holding reference to the context. I can't really tell in detail why until I see entire code/use case. 

But using interfaces is in general cleaner, more flexible and advised over inheritance. With an interface you use only the things you need, with inheritance, you may pull other things with you that you dont actually need.

Comment: Awesome, great answer, thanks for explaining well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {
public static GlobalClass ginstance;
public void onCreate() {
    ginstance = getApplicationContext();
}
```

}

and then modify your manifest file

```
<application
    android:name="com.you.yourapp.GlobalClass"
```

Comment: This brings up the lint warning `Do not place Android context classes in static fields`

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful when you pass Context instances around your app since its very easy to cause a memory leak on Android.
Best answer to your question is DO NOT DO IT, instances to android specific objects (Activity, Fragments, Application - Context) shouldn't be hold/referenced longer than their respective life-cycles.

When you declare any View to be static, your causing memory leak since static view is not tided to Activity/Fragment life-cycle (but still holding the reference to it) than rather on Class that resides in and cannot be GC-d (garbage collected) when respective Activity/Fragment completes.

In order to avoid memory leaks consider:

- changing your code organization
- using one of the `event bus` libraries [like this one](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)()
- using plain java interfaces to communicate between components

If you have some non-android methods that require context you can always pass `Application context` with

```
 getActivity().getApplicationContext() // Application Context will live as long your app lives so you don't have to worry about memory leaks
```

Same applies if you want to get activity reference from your fragment: 
 `getActivity()` will return Activity object which you can cast to your Activity and later use it to call appropriate methods

Comment: So you're saying DON'T do what @OutOfBounds 94 is recommending? Rather, you should essentially pass your main activity as an argument in a cascading manner all the way down to whichever children need it?

Comment: Depending on the case:
 - if you need context outside android specific classes use ApplicationContext
- if you need to communicate with your activity (from Fragment) use getActivityContext();